# Struts 2 - Converting new lines (\r\n) in <br /> elements using <s:property>

Tags: java, struts2, newline

Is there a way to convert new lines in a `<br />` HTML element using the `<s:property>` tag?

For example I have the following string value in a `sampleValue` property:

```
Hello world\r\nThis is a new line
```

to be rendered with `<s:property value="%{sampleValue}" />` like:

```
Hello world<br />This is a new line
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no facility in struts2 for this. If for some reason you have preformated the text, then I guess the easiest would be:

```
<pre>
  <s:property value="sampleValue"/>
</pre>
```

It is possible of course to get a regex into the display to replace "\r\n" with <br/> but there is something very ugly about that (I also find the solution above with <pre> quite ugly too but most will find that easier to understand than a regex in the middle of a jsp).

Note: Instead of <pre> you can use the css property "white-space" with a value of "pre" see: http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_text_white-space.asp for more information on the css white space property.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for dredging this up, but now that I figured it out, I wanted a place to post the solution in case I needed it again. ;?)

```
<s:property escapeHtml="false" value="sampleValue.replace(\"\n\", \" <br />\")" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, struts obviously escapes by default all meta-signs ...
just do the following:

```
<s:fielderror escape="false" />
<s:actionmessage escape="false" />
```

and the linebreak should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

Line of code in java file:

```
datos += rs.getString(7) + "<br/>";
```

Line of code in .jsp file:

```
<s:property escapeHtml="false" value="datos" />
```